# Types of Java Bean in IBM Websphere commerce

Tags: java, ejb, websphere-commerce

How many types of Java Beans are there in IBM Websphere Commerce?

I have searched in IBM info centre a lot but only find these Beans:

```
Entity Bean
Session Bean
And Message Driven Bean
```

but I heard a few days back that there are some other kind of Beans also in IBM WS like, smart beans. what are they?

Could anyone please provide me the name and description of all the types of javaBeans used in(supported by) IBM?

Comment: This is ready answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502533/entitybean-sessionbean-databean-and-accessbean

Comment: All beans might be a bit broad and hard to maintain (as a list on StackOverflow). Martinatime's answer provides a good start

Answer (score 3):

There are two other main Bean types that WebSphere Commerce uses. They are not part of the J2EE standards.

- AccessBean
- DataBean

The AccessBean is a convenience wrapper for Entity and Session Beans (they may also be for Message Driven Beans but I don't have experience using those). Basically, they provide a mechanism to hide the details of using EJBs such as looking up the EJB and the various EJB methods.

The DataBean is a further wrapper that extends the AccessBeans for use on JSPs. They typically    and helper methods, aggregation of data, formatting, and catching of exceptions. A subtype is the SmartDataBean that uses information from the request in order to populate the bean's key fields so that they can self populate when initialized.

Answer (score -1):

yes, there are smartBeans, Command Beans which are sub type of databeans in ibm wcs.
    com.ibm.commerce.SmartDataBean.
    com.ibm.commerce.CommandDataBean
    com.ibm.commerce.InputDataBean (optional)

Please see below link for more details.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/csdjsp_pages_and_data_beans.htm?cp=SSZLC2_7.0.0%2F9-7-0-3